# how to use addin developed with microsoft.sharepoint.dll in other system

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've developed an outlook addin in vs2013. The development machine has sharepoint installed. My code has:

```js
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
```

But when I run this code on a client machine it shows an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlgF.png).In some sites they suggest using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you expected. `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` is a *server side* library which is *part of* Microsoft SharePoint and hence can neither be referenced nor used otherwise in a client-side environment such as an Outlook add-in.

What you are looking for is [Client-Side Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csom/info), or CSOM for short. However, developing CSOM apps is a completely different story, needs slightly different knowledge and skills. The bad news is most of your SharePoint-related work will *have to* be redeveloped almost from scratch.

If your SharePoint integration isn't heavy, you might be able to achieve what you want with SharePoint's web services, either REST or SOAP. There an [article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx) providing insight to various types of SharePoint APIs and providing guidance which API to use in what situation. You shoudl read this first.

Answer (score 0):

we can't use using Microsoft.SharePoint; in sharepoint not installed system.
we need to use using Microsoft.SharePoint.client; for client system and use client object model code.